# How can I modify this to show number of posts-per-month?

Tags: archives

I use the code below to produce a list of 'month+posts that month'.

What do I need to do to show, alongside each month, the number of posts that month?

```
<?php
$previous_year = $year = 0;
$previous_month = $month = 0;
$dl_open = false;

// Get the posts
$myposts =         get_posts('numberposts=-1&orderby=post_date&order=DESC&post_type=byte');
?>

<?php foreach($myposts as $post) : ?>

<?php
// Setup the post variables
setup_postdata($post);
$year = mysql2date('Y', $post->post_date);
$month = mysql2date('n', $post->post_date);
$day = mysql2date('d', $post->post_date);
?>

<?php if($year != $previous_year || $month != $previous_month) : ?>

<?php if($dl_open == true) : ?>
</dl>
<?php endif; ?>

<h3><?php the_time('F Y'); ?></h3>

<dl id="post-list">

<?php $dl_open = true; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php $previous_year = $year; $previous_month = $month; ?>

<dt><?php the_time('d'); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="read it"><?php the_title(); ?></a></dt>
<dd><?php the_excerpt(); ?></dd>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</dl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply use `wp_get_archives` and modify it's parameters?

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives

Comment: ...Thanks. Good point. I hadn't thought of it - probably because I've been using this code for ages.

Comment: Hi @gulliver, please accept one of the answers that worked for you so this question can be marked as resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

Employ a counter. On every month change, output it before you close each `<dl>` and zero it.

Now, if you want it printed before the posts (eg. inside or near the `<h3>`) you probably shouldn't output your html directly, but instead save it in a string, or use `ob`, and flush it upon month change.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how to do that, so will search some more to learn about your suggestion.